# How to manage Dto objects and mapping in MVC when Table A joins to Table B multiple times

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, api, automapper, dto

So I'm building a basic website with MVC 5 which has job details for a construction site. In the Job model, there are three columns which all link to a model called Employee. So,

ProjectManagerID
SuperID
EstimatorID

all link to the Employee model (EmployeeID).

Good. So far I've been able to use InverseProperty and ForeignKey to be able to include the EmployeeName that corresponds to each of the fields in the Job model.

What I'm struggling with is how to approach a scenario where there is an api that pulls the job data, maps it to a job Dto - and then the job Dto is able to retrieve the relevant domain lookups.

I've already got the API working and pulling back non-domain related data. It's also retrieving data from related entities where there is only one join to that table. To achieve this I've created dtos for job, employee and all the lookups, e.g. JobStatus. Automapper is being used to map the dtos.

What I can't seem to figure out - and I have done plenty of research - is how to use dtos and automapper to map model A to model B three times.

As mentioned there are Dtos for job and employee. So what I've tried is creating another dto for PMEmployee called PMEmployeeDto and referenced it from the JobDto. Then I create a mapping in MappingProfile.cs - mapping JobDto to PMEmployeeDto.

Testing the api call with Postman, I get the following error:

> "exceptionMessage": "Missing type map configuration or unsupported
>   mapping.\r\n\r\nMapping
>   types:\r\nEmployee_138B77EF10368E30038E0A477A4BD4DFFFA659B2AD8A386CE364C5A44C213B5B
>   -> PMEmployeeDto\r\nSystem.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.Employee_138B77EF10368E30038E0A477A4BD4DFFFA659B2AD8A386CE364C5A44C213B5B
>   -> MDMWebApp.Dtos.PMEmployeeDto\r\n\r\nDestination path:\r\nJobDto.PMEmployee.PMEmployee\r\n\r\nSource
>   value:\r\nSystem.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.Employee_138B77EF10368E30038E0A477A4BD4DFFFA659B2AD8A386CE364C5A44C213B5B",
>           "exceptionType": "AutoMapper.AutoMapperMappingException",
>           "stackTrace": "   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectListIterator`2.MoveNext()\r\n   at
>   System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereEnumerableIterator`1.MoveNext()\r\n   at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeList(JsonWriter
>   writer, IEnumerable values, JsonArrayContract contract, JsonProperty
>   member, JsonContainerContract collectionContract, JsonProperty
>   containerProperty)\r\n   at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeValue(JsonWriter
>   writer, Object value, JsonContract valueContract, JsonProperty member,
>   JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty
>   containerProperty)\r\n   at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.Serialize(JsonWriter
>   jsonWriter, Object value, Type objectType)\r\n   at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.SerializeInternal(JsonWriter
>   jsonWriter, Object value, Type objectType)\r\n   at
>   System.Net.Http.Formatting.BaseJsonMediaTypeFormatter.WriteToStream(Type
>   type, Object value, Stream writeStream, Encoding
>   effectiveEncoding)\r\n   at
>   System.Net.Http.Formatting.JsonMediaTypeFormatter.WriteToStream(Type
>   type, Object value, Stream writeStream, Encoding
>   effectiveEncoding)\r\n   at
>   System.Net.Http.Formatting.BaseJsonMediaTypeFormatter.WriteToStream(Type
>   type, Object value, Stream writeStream, HttpContent content)\r\n   at
>   System.Net.Http.Formatting.BaseJsonMediaTypeFormatter.WriteToStreamAsync(Type
>   type, Object value, Stream writeStream, HttpContent content,
>   TransportContext transportContext, CancellationToken
>   cancellationToken)\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location
>   where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Http.WebHost.HttpControllerHandler.d__1b.MoveNext()"

Here is the JobDto:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;


namespace MDMWebApp.Dtos
{
    public class JobDto
    {

        [Required]
        public int JobID { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string JobNumber { get; set; }

        [StringLength(255)]
        public string JobDescription { get; set; }

        public JobStatusDto JobStatus { get; set; }

        public JobTypeDto JobType { get; set; }

        public InsuranceTypeDto InsuranceType { get; set; }

        public ClientDto Client { get; set; }

        public PMEmployeeDto PMEmployee { get; set; }

    }
}
```

The PMEmployeeDto:

```
namespace MDMWebApp.Dtos
{
    public class PMEmployeeDto
    {
        public int EmployeeID { get; set; }
        public string EmployeeFullName { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And the MappingProfile:

```
using AutoMapper;
using MDMWebApp.Dtos;
using MDMWebApp.Models;

namespace MDMWebApp.App_Start
{
    public class MappingProfile : Profile
    {
        public MappingProfile()
        {
            Mapper.CreateMap<Employee, EmployeeDto>();
            Mapper.CreateMap<EmployeeDto, Employee>();
            Mapper.CreateMap<InsuranceType, InsuranceTypeDto>();
            Mapper.CreateMap<Job, JobDto>();
            Mapper.CreateMap<JobType, JobTypeDto>();
            Mapper.CreateMap<JobStatus, JobStatusDto>();
            Mapper.CreateMap<JobTitle, JobTitleDto>();
            Mapper.CreateMap<JCSummary, JCSummaryDto>();
            Mapper.CreateMap<Client, ClientDto>();
            Mapper.CreateMap<JobDto, PMEmployeeDto>();
        }
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: unless im misunderstanding, it seems like `PMEmployeeDto` should be mapped to a `PMEmployee` and not a `JobDto`. are you actually trying to turn a `JobDto` into a `PMEmployeeDto` in code?

Comment: Thanks Greg. Honestly I've at this for so long now is was the best I could come up with. Teasing out what you suggested, [PMEmployee] would need to be created first. Would a ViewModel work here?

Comment: In MVC the Model is usually intended to be a ViewModel.  If you had a View that you were putting this data on, your Model/ViewModel might look like Job{ int JobId, string JobNumber, string JobDescription, JobStatus Status, Employee PM, Employee Super, Employee Estimator }.  I don't see here why you are using DTOs.  Can you explain how they fit in?

Comment: Mike, the base models are part of the domain model of the application, i.e. implementation detail which can change frequently as I implement new features. These changes can potentially break existing clients that are dependent on the models. Dtos reduce the chances of my api breaking as I refactor the domain model. Also in practice api's should never receive data from domain objects. Another issue is that by using regular domain objects we are open up security holes in the application.

Comment: This also goes for View Models. Not saying they can't form part of the solution, just saying I'd think twice about calling them the bonafide solution. Going to create an appropriate view model as recommended and eliminate exposure of the model to the client via a Dto. I'll report back with the answer if this works out successfully.

Answer (score 0):

ViewModels worked fine here. I'll caveat that with the application is internal and will not be exposed to the internet so I didn't have to go into pen testing and that type of thing.